# how to back up and restore postfix mails

Tags: shell-script, postfix

I'm new to postfix and intended to start using it long time so I have simple question how to back up my mails and if I need to restore those back ups on other computer who does I proceed

Note : No database(sql) involved

I need this details be course I was going to create **bashscript** that backup **all emails** in postfix has (send /received) for  every user and run this script with crone 1s a week

I haven't configure specific dir to as mail box so i think postfix use its default location for it `/var/mail/[username]`

Comment: Are you sure those are actually the mails which were given to Postfix (for transfert or distribution) that you want to backup? Mails usually don't stay long in Postfix's queues. Don't you rather want to backup the mails you have already received (i.e. *delivered* by Postfix, thus no longer under Postfix's care)? If so, please clarify your question and tell us how are handled the received mails (IMAP? direct local delivery in `/var/spool`?).

Comment: currently I use default mail_dir and yes I need send and received both mails for all users backup and when i need restored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't state what mails, exactly, you wish to back up, but I'm going to assume you mean the delivered mails in users' inboxes.

These are just files on the filesystem, so all you need to do is use a regular backup program that backs up files. Some options:

- bacula or its fork, bareos (write to tapes, real or virtual)
- amanda (same)
- rsync-snapshot, (creates snapshots on remote servers)
- backuppc (same)

... And many more. I suggest you do some research on one or more of these options and ask a more detailed question afterwards.

Comment: Thnk you mate this was grate info and will help on future work but here  I was trying to create bash scrip which generate  zip  or tar files per week and restore using those files on another machine which has same users . what kind of things should l concern when  restoring and backup ?